# ScalaJS: Find the length of an array stored as js.Dynamic

Tags: arrays, json, scala.js

I'm using both Scala.JS and Akka.JS to learn about client-side, actor-based apps.  When the user selects a country from a list of countries, a list of cities in that country is constructed.  This part works fine.

However, some countries are listed as having only one city (E.G. Hong Kong contains only Hong Kong), so when I display the list of cities, I'd first like to check the length of the city list (which is of type js.Dynamic).  If its >1, I'll add a non-selectable placeholder "Select a city" to the dropdown list and then build the city list.  As long as I do this arbitrarily, everything works fine.

In spite of the fact that I can quite happily `map` a function across the `cityList` of type `js.Dynamic`, it seems that testing the length of `cityList` is not something that can be done directly, even though the `cities` JSON object is an array:

```
"cities": [
    {
      "cityName": "Parròquia de Sant Julià de Lòria",
      "cityId": 3039162,
      "coords": {
        "lon": 1.48247,
        "lat": 42.462471
      }
    },
    {
      "cityName": "Pas de la Casa",
      "cityId": 3039604,
      "coords": {
        "lon": 1.73361,
        "lat": 42.54277
      }
    },
```

If I try:

```
if (cityList.length == 1)
```

or

```
if (cityList.size == 1)
```

Then I get compilation warning that `js.Dynamic and Int are unrelated` and so cannot be compared for equality, and if I try

```
if (cityList.size.asInstanceOf[Int] == 1)
```

or

```
if (cityList.length.asInstanceOf[Int] == 1)
```

this always fails because `Int` is not a member of `undefined`.

Finally, I tried

```
if ((cityList.asInstanceOf[Seq[js.Dynamic]]).size == 1)
```

But this blows up with `[object Object] is not an instance of scala.collection.Seq`

How do I obtain the length of a `js.Dynamic` without first unloading it into some other data structure (which I'd like to avoid since that's double-handling the data)?

Chris W

Comment: Try this one again: `if (cityList.length.asInstanceOf[Int] == 1)`, it should work. Otherwise, please include the complete error message for that snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, I'm sure I tried this, but as srjd pointed out, the correct answer `if (cityList.length.asInstanceOf[Int] == 1)`